# ValidatorError on adding records

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to add a record to my mongodb database. I am sure that I am providing correct values, although mongoose is considering them missing. Here's my Schema -

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

    var SocketUserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: String,
        username: {
            type: String,
            unique: true,
            required: true
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        devices: [{
            name: String,
            platform: String
        }],
        first_ip: {
            type: String,
            default: "0.0.0.0"
        },
        last_login_ip: {
            type: String,
            default: "0.0.0.0"
        },
        added_at: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        },
    });

    module.exports = mongoose.model('SocketUser', SocketUserSchema);
```

Here's my create code snippet -

```
console.log('registered triggered ' + data);
/*var jsonData = data;
jsonData.first_ip = clientIpAddress;
jsonData.last_login_ip = clientIpAddress;*/
var user = new SocketUser({
username: data.username,
     password: data.password,
     devices: data.devices,
     first_ip: clientIpAddress,
     last_login_ip: clientIpAddress
});

SocketUser.create(user, function(err, post) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('error',err);
    } else {
        console.log('success');
    }
});
```

Here's the sample user data I am sending -

```
{
  "username": "nexus",
  "password": "noob",
  "devices": [
    {
      "name": "Nexus",
      "platform": "android"
    }
  ]
}
```

And here's the error I am getting -

```
{
  "message": "SocketUser validation failed",
  "name": "ValidationError",
  "errors": {
    "username": {
      "properties": {
        "type": "required",
        "message": "Path `{PATH}` is required.",
        "path": "username"
      },
      "message": "Path `username` is required.",
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "kind": "required",
      "path": "username"
    },
    "password": {
      "properties": {
        "type": "required",
        "message": "Path `{PATH}` is required.",
        "path": "password"
      },
      "message": "Path `password` is required.",
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "kind": "required",
      "path": "password"
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, username and password both fields are there in the data, but still it's giving error. I have tried sending data json directly to Create method and also tried save method too. Both gives same error. Is there anything I am missing here?

**Update:**
I tried validating the record, before adding it to database and it gave same error -

```
user.validate(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("error "+err.message+"\nFull error: "+JSON.stringify(err));
    }
    else {
    }
});

registered triggered {"username":"nexus","password":"noob","devices":[{"name":"N
exus","platform":"android"}]}
error SocketUser validation failed
Full error: {"message":"SocketUser validation failed","name":"ValidationError","
errors":{"password":{"properties":{"type":"required","message":"Path `{PATH}` is
 required.","path":"password"},"message":"Path `password` is required.","name":"
ValidatorError","kind":"required","path":"password"},"username":{"properties":{"
type":"required","message":"Path `{PATH}` is required.","path":"username"},"mess
age":"Path `username` is required.","name":"ValidatorError","kind":"required","p
ath":"username"}}}
```

I am unable to find the issue with username and password. I want these fields as required fields for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue, I checked if I am getting data.username and data.password properly or not. They were resulting in `undefined`. Then I realized that the data is actually a string, not an object. So I parsed it into json and then I got it working. Here's the code to do it, in case somebody get stuck at the same issue -

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```